# Android App Icon

Tags: android, icons

Could someone please tell me how I can make the icon for my app fill the square? There's currently black parts above and below the icon.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html